# Symmetric polynomial constructed from symmetric group

Tags: polynomials, permutations, symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials

Let $n$ be a positive integer, $S_n$ be the symmetric group. For a permutation $p=[p_1,\dots,p_n]\in S_n$, define $x^p := x_1^{p_1}\cdots x_n^{p_n}$. It can be seen that the following polynomial is symmetric:
$$F(x_1,\dots,x_n):=\frac1{n!}\sum_{p\in S_n}\ \prod_{C\in S_n/\langle p\rangle} \big(1 + \prod_{q\in C} x^q\big),$$
where $S_n/\langle p\rangle$ denotes the (left) cosets of the (cyclic) subgroup $\langle p\rangle$ in $S_n$.

> Q: Is there an explicit expression for $F(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ in terms of any "standard" symmetric polynomials ($e$, $h$, $m$, $s$, or $p$)?